# Adding API key auth to existing API

Tags: c#, azure-ad-b2c

If we have a .NET API currently validating users through B2C flows on azure where the API validates the token from the FE with B2C.

How could we implement functionality for daemons to consume the API as well if there is no user interaction to get a key from b2c?

I believe this is called client credentials flow, but I know this does not exist on b2c?

Any ideas on how we could achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

This [workaround](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/application-types#daemonsserver-side-applications) may work for your case.

"Although the OAuth 2.0 client credentials grant flow is not currently directly supported by the Azure AD B2C authentication service, you can set up client credential flow using Azure AD and the [Microsoft identity platform](https://login.microsoftonline.com/your-tenant-name.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/token) /token endpoint for an application in your Azure AD B2C tenant. An Azure AD B2C tenant shares some functionality with Azure AD enterprise tenants.

To set up client credential flow, see Azure Active Directory v2.0 and the OAuth 2.0 client credentials flow. A successful authentication results in the receipt of a token formatted so that it can be used by Azure AD as described in Azure AD token reference".